# MongoDB aggregation pipeline: counting occurrences of words in list field from matching documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. My documents all have various things and a *keywords* field with a list of strings as values. (The lists can contain duplicates, which are significant.) Suppose the following documents match the query:

```
{'original_id': 33, 'keywords': ['dog', 'cat', 'goat', 'dog']},
{'original_id': 34, 'keywords': ['dog', 'kitten', 'goat', 'moose']},
{'original_id': 35, 'keywords': ['moose', 'elk']}
```

I want to get back a map of the keywords found with the number of occurrences of each in the set of matching documents:

```
{'dog': 3, 'cat': 1, 'goat':2, 'kitten': 1, 'moose': 2, 'elk': 1}
```

(Note that *dog* in document 33 gets counted twice.)

I'm currently doing this from PyMongo by creating a `Counter`, calling `collection_name.find(...)` and then iterating through all the documents updating the counter with each keywords field. But I would like to make the process more efficient by doing it within MongoDB.

Is this kind of counting possible in an aggregation pipeline? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `keywords` array
- `$group` by `keywords` and count total
- `$group` by null and construct array of key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert above array to object key-value format
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$keywords"c },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$keywords",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      keywords: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$keywords" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fGy0Gw2G4Ij)

Comment: Thanks for the clear, step-by-step explanation -- that has given me a much better understanding of how the aggregation works!